# How to check if a (string) is equal a (string inside an Array)? Can I check it with an If-statement?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, typo3, fluid

I want to check if the String matches one of the Strings in an Array.

Is it possible with TYPO3 fluid or with vhs?

```
<f:if condition="{string} ?? {anArrayOfStrings}">
  <f:then>
    <p>Message</p>
  </f:then>
  <f:else>

  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I used VHS "v:condition.string.contains". It works :)

```
<v:condition.string.contains needle="{string}" haystack="{anArrayOfStrings}">
  <f:then>
    Message
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
  </f:else>
</v:condition.string.contains>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fluid doesn't have an inArray ViewHelper by default, but VHS does (`v:if.iterator.contains`). See https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.8.2/If/Iterator/ContainsViewHelper.html

If you want to do it without VHS, you can create a custom ViewHelper. More on that you can find here https://www.andrerinas.de/tutorials/typo3-in-array-viewhelper.html (in German, but the code should be clear enough even if you don't understand German)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I tried the VHS v:if.iterator.contains but it didn't work. It throws an error:
'Error: The ViewHelper "<v:if.iterator.contains>" could not be resolved. Based on your spelling, the system would load the class "FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\If\Iterator\ContainsViewHelper", however this class does not exist. (error code 1407060572). Template source chunk: <v:if.iterator.contains needle="{string}" haystack="{anArrayOfStrings}">'

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VHS, or custom ViewHelpers.

Just use `f:for` to loop over the array, and set a variable if you find it:

```
<f:variable name="stringFound" value="0" />
<f:for each="{anArrayOfStrings}" as="arrayString">
    <f:if condition="{string} == {arrayString}">
        <f:variable name="stringFound" value="1" />
    </f:if>
</f:for>
    
<f:if condition="{stringFound} == 1">
    <f:then>
        <p>String found in array</p>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <p>String not in array</p>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 does not have such a ViewHelper. Please use ViewHelper of EXT:vhs

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.8.2/If/Iterator/ContainsViewHelper.html

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<v:if needle="{string}" haystack="{anArrayOfStrings}">
  <f:then>
    <p>Message</p>
  </f:then>
  <f:else>

  </f:else>
</v:if>
```

Don't know if this will work with f:than. Maybe try v:than or the than-Attribute of this ViewHelper.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I tried the VHS v:if.iterator.contains but it didn't work. It throws an error:
Error: The ViewHelper "<v:if.iterator.contains>" could not be resolved. Based on your spelling, the system would load the class "FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\If\Iterator\ContainsViewHelper", however this class does not exist. (error code 1407060572). Template source chunk: <v:if.iterator.contains needle="{string}" haystack="{anArrayOfStrings}">

Comment: I have updated my answer. The namespace is missing. Please use it as described or as xmlns-Attribute described here: https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concrete example that worked for me with TYPO3 9.5.14. Based on a chosen section frame ('custom-45' or 'custom-50') fluid renders a special div-element with the class "my-custom-frame", otherwhise it uses the default rendering:

```
<v:condition.string.contains needle="{data.frame_class}" haystack="{'custom-45','custom-50'}">
    <f:then>
        <div class="my-custom-frame">
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <div id="c{data.uid}" class="frame frame-{data.frame_class} frame-type-{data.CType} frame-layout-{data.layout}{f:if(condition: data.space_before_class, then: ' frame-space-before-{data.space_before_class}')}{f:if(condition: data.space_after_class, then: ' frame-space-after-{data.space_after_class}')}">
    </f:else>
</v:condition.string.contains>
```

The needle is the chosen section frame for a content element. In the haystack you find the values that result in a true condition. I used this to shorten the or-syntax:

```
<f:if condition="{data.frame_class} == 'custom-45' || {data.frame_class} == 'custom-50'">
    <f:then>
        <div class="my-custom-frame">
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <div id="c{data.uid}" class="frame frame-{data.frame_class} frame-type-{data.CType} frame-layout-{data.layout}{f:if(condition: data.space_before_class, then: ' frame-space-before-{data.space_before_class}')}{f:if(condition: data.space_after_class, then: ' frame-space-after-{data.space_after_class}')}">
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

A namespace declaration in the fluid template was not necessary. The used VHS: Fluid ViewHelpers-Extension was 6.0.0.